# input many values into input method python3

Tags: python

i need to input values split the space

output should return me sum of this values

so if i putting `1 4`

my code should return `5`

```
a,b = input().split(" ")
print (int(a)+int(b))
```

this code is working

but i need to define variables!

how i can input 5 value? 10 values? and don't define this variables somewhere

for example i want input `1 1 1 1 1`

and get `5`

Comment: Can the numbers be floating point? What if the user inputs something other than numbers?

Comment: this example just for ints

Answer (score 3):

```
# input '1 1 1 1 1'
list_of_values = input().split(" ")
# list_of_values = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
print(sum(int(a) for a in list_of_values))
# sum of [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] is 5
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner pythonic way:

```
print('Sum is : ' + str(sum(list(map(int, input("Enter Numbers: ").split())))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
vars = input(">")
vars = vars.split()
sum = 0

#calculate sum
for number in vars:
    try:
        int(number)
        sum += int(number)
    except:
        pass

#prettify
tempVars = vars
vars = []
for number in tempVars:
    try:
        int(number)
        vars.append(number)
    except:
        pass

print(f"Sum of {vars}: {sum}")
```